# Q: (docx2pdf) using python

Tags: python, docx2pdf

I use python to write code to convert docx to pdf, but I get this error:
On Windows: pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, 'Microsoft Word', 'Command failed', 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\ 1033\WDMAIN11.CHM', 36966, -2146824090), None)
On MAC: The program automatically opens that docx file and cannot convert it.
I need your help!

i use python 3.12 and pycharm ide, installed docx2pdf

updated:
I'm dowload plugin from microsoft: SaveAsPDFandXPS and install, because MS Office need this pugin to convert, that all, thankyou

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Is there any specific reason you are using python 3.12 (since it's an early developer beta)

Comment: Update your python to 3.7 or higher.

Comment: now i'm using python 3.8, but same errror above :(

Comment: Have you tried another docx file? It is possible that it throws an error only in a specific file.

Comment: I using office 7 on my window and office 12 on my MACos, but same error, im try another docx file but  same error :(

Comment: I finally fixed this, just add plugin from microsoft: SaveAsPDFandXPS. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Can you please answer your question to help other people with the same problem?

Comment: I'm dowload plugin from microsoft: SaveAsPDFandXPS and install, that all

Answer (score 1):

I recommand you use Python Version 3.10.8 below.
Because Python Version 3.12.0 is Only developer beta.

you follow me. it's very simple.
`pip install python-docx`
You do it on cmd(terminal).

```
import docx

# Open the .docs file
doc = docx.Document('document.docs')

# Save the file as pdf
doc.save('document.pdf')
```

Comment: it worked, but i can't open that pdf file, now i'm ussing python 3.8

Comment: I thought you have docx file is bad file. just another docx file use with this code.

Comment: I try another docx file, but same errror!

Comment: What is your environment like? What is your environment like? Word document version, operating system, Python version
Then write a new word document and try it.